# Benchmarking - g++ produces different code from MSVC

Tags: c++, memory, visual-c++, g++

I'm writing a benchmark, that measures speed and memory use of my program. I work in VS19, but my test will be run on a linux machine, so I need to compile it in g++. My problem is, that in VS19 my code produces correct results that I expect, compiled with g++ it produces wrong results.

The issue is in memory measurement. In Functions.cpp I have overloaded *new* and *delete*

```
AllocationMetrics s_allocationMetrics;

void* operator new(size_t size) {
    //cout << "Allocate " << size << " bytes\n";
    s_allocationMetrics.totalMemory += size;
    return malloc(size);
}

void operator delete(void* ptr, size_t size) {
    //cout << "Deallocate " << size << " bytes\n";
    s_allocationMetrics.totalFree += size;
    free(ptr);
}
```

and in Functions.h I have created this struct, that tracks the memory allocations

```
struct AllocationMetrics {
    uint64_t totalMemory = 0;
    uint64_t totalFree = 0;
    uint64_t getCurrentUsage() { return totalMemory - totalFree; }
    uint64_t maxMem=0;
    void setMaxMem() {
        uint64_t temp= getCurrentUsage();
        if (temp > maxMem)
            maxMem = temp;
    }
    void resetMaxMem() { maxMem = 0; }
};
```

In the in functions from Functions.cpp, that I need measured, I call *setMaxMem* and in my Benchmark.cpp I call *resetMaxMem*, when appropriate. The struct is declared in Functionc.cpp, and in all other .cpp files it is declared as extern.

For this example, I run my benchmark 6x in a loop and with Visual Studio's MSVC I get the expected memory results, with all possible settings (debug, release, etc).

```
Params:                 1063 x 24       5       5       255
        Sorting                 0.0084792s              0.36439MB
        Stripes                 0.0179886s              1.64792MB

Params:                 1063 x 24       5       5       255
        Sorting                 0.0080979s              0.364406MB
        Stripes                 0.0165975s              1.64794MB

Params:                 1063 x 24       5       5       255
        Sorting                 0.0080586s              0.364422MB
        Stripes                 0.0163024s              1.64795MB

Params:                 1063 x 24       5       5       255
        Sorting                 0.0081503s              0.364438MB
        Stripes                 0.016274s               1.64797MB

Params:                 1063 x 24       5       5       255
        Sorting                 0.0079747s              0.364454MB
        Stripes                 0.0170647s              1.64799MB

Params:                 1063 x 24       5       5       255
        Sorting                 0.0079046s              0.364486MB
        Stripes                 0.0160469s              1.64801MB
```

When I compile the same code with g++ compiler `g++ Source.cpp Functionc.cpp benchmarking.cpp`, I get these wrong results

```
Params:                 1063 x 24       5       5       255
        Sorting                 0.063828s               1.0806MB
        Stripes                 0.171574s               3.73044MB

Params:                 1063 x 24       5       5       255
        Sorting                 0.061869s               4.32227MB
        Stripes                 0.172318s               6.97212MB

Params:                 1063 x 24       5       5       255
        Sorting                 0.067859s               7.56395MB
        Stripes                 0.170573s               10.2138MB

Params:                 1063 x 24       5       5       255
        Sorting                 0.063863s               10.8057MB
        Stripes                 0.171541s               13.4555MB

Params:                 1063 x 24       5       5       255
        Sorting                 0.062963s               14.0473MB
        Stripes                 0.170528s               16.6972MB

Params:                 1063 x 24       5       5       255
        Sorting                 0.064827s               17.2891MB
        Stripes                 0.171541s               19.9389MB
```

Everything else is correct in g++ compilation, I tried different optimization levels, this memory bug didn't change. I use g++ (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0 version. I also tried running this with clang, but same mistake appeared.

It appears as if the *delete* overload didn't take an effect with g++, or that *delete* isn't called when freeing variables.
I tried compiling on both Windows and Linux (same version of g++), this bug appeared in both versions.

**EDIT1**: forgot a line of code with *temp* definition.

Comment: From [operator_delete](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) (5,6), *"except that it's unspecified whether (1-2) or (5-6) is called when deleting objects of incomplete type and arrays of non-class and trivially-destructible class types."*. Is it your case?

Comment: Probably unrelated: Shouldn't `AllocationMetrics s_allocationMetrics;` be `extern AllocationMetrics s_allocationMetrics;`? Also, where is `temp` defined?

Comment: @TedLyngmo forgot the line, it's in setMaxMem(), now added to the post.
s_allocationMetrics is extern in all other files (Source.cpp, benchmarking.cpp) but in is not extern in Functions.cpp

Comment: @AleksanderMarkovskyy Ok, and `s_allocationMetrics`? Why isn't that `extern`?

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't fully understand, what are incomplete types? I mostly deal with float and short vectors. In g++ operator delete isn't called a single time, whereas in MSVC it seems to be called everytime a variable goes out of scope.

Comment: Note says that `void operator delete(void*)` might be called instead of `void operator delete(void* ptr, size_t size)` in some cases. Incomplete types are types without a full definition (so just forwarding classes or class not yet fully defined (as the one used in CRTP) or `void`).

Comment: Which standard do you use for gcc/clang? C++14?

Comment: @Jarod42  c++14 for clang and default for gcc, I assume 14 as well

Comment: @Jarod42 I believe what you are saying is true. Do you have any idea, how I can use this fact to make my code work for gcc?

Comment: Old way was to put size in the data of pointer returned. As alternative, overload `void operator delete(void*)` and use a mapping to retrieve the size might be an option for testing. Another alternative might be to wrap your type into non-trivially destructible types...

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. I've tried to recreate your issue using gcc 11, but failed - everything runs as expected.

Comment: @Jarod42 can you post your comment as an answer? 
GCC 6.3.0 chose to use `void operator delete(void*)` instead of  `void operator delete(void*, size_t size)`. I solved the issue by upgrading to GCC 11.2.0, which produces the expected behavior.

Comment: @AleksanderMarkovskyy: Feel free to write your own answer (and even copy paste my relevant comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684539/jarod42) for the useful comments.

The issue lies in GCC 6.3.0 choosing a different overload of the delete, namely `delete(void*)` instead of `delete(void*, size_t size)` which I have targeted.
In order to have GCC behave I upgraded it to a newer 11.2.0 version.